# Server Side Geolocating?

Tags: java, html, geolocation

So the method most used in the recent past to detect a users location when they arrive at a website is ip geolocating. This can be done server side, which is nice because say your home page is what you want the user to see if their location can't be determined...if the location is found its easy to redirect them to the proper page and it doesn't interrupt their initial experience on the site at all.

When the ip address is coming from a mobile network is gets tricky because the ip address method is not accurate any longer. The only solution i've seen used in this situation is HTML5's Geolocation API. Problem with this is that the page has to load first so a smooth redirect when the location is found is not possible.

Is there a server side method for obtaining an accurate location, specifically if the user is coming from a mobile network?

Answer (score 0):

How accurate do you need it to be?  The location can still be pretty accurate even for a mobile device. Have look at maxmind.com - http://www.maxmind.com/en/locate_my_ip.  There is a free database, accurate to city level. If you need more accurate data, you can subscribe.

Comment: Hmm...Maxmind is what im currently using. For some reason when I check my ip on sites like whatismyip.com from a mobile network I get locations like 2 states over. I figured it was because the service wasn't actually coming from a tower nearby. Are mobile ips pinpointable like wifi ips?